# TFS API - How to know if TestRun is related to PBI or Bug

Tags: c#, tfs

I've a range date used to query TFS in order to retrieve a collection of test runs.

For each one of them I need to retrieve a few of informations such as Id of linked PBI or Bug related to test run item, however the ITestRun class seems not provide useful informations.

Is there any way to get these infos?

Comment: Can you share what did you try? how do you get the test runs?

Comment: Somethting like this: testManagementService.QueryTestRuns("select * From TestRun WHERE [IsAutomated] = 0 AND [LastUpdated] >= '11/06/2019 00:00:00'")

Comment: test run can't be linked to work items, are you sure your test tuns linked/related to PBI/Bug?

Comment: test run I assume is related to TestCase which in turns is related to work item (pbi or bug). isn't it?

Comment: yea, it make sense, so in the test run you have "test plan", check the test case in the plan to which work item are linked.

Comment: Yes, TestRun provide PlanID, but Plan contains more informations, I'm not able to understand how test run is related to.